# How to quickly get one dimensional int array from int **?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, memory-management

I would like to get one dimensional array from my double int pointer. The memory for pointer is allocated like this :

```
listOfTxtsContents = new int *[ROWS];
for( int i = 0 ; i < ROWS ; i++ )
{
    listOfTxtsContents[i] = new int[COLUMNS];
    for(int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; ++j)
        listOfTxtsContents[i][j] = 0;
}
```

Then each row contains some data where I would like to put it in the array in such a way so that the 1D array will be filled with consecutive rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure something like this should work:

```
array[ROWS * COLUMNS];
for(size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
  memcpy(array + i * COLUMNS, listOfTxtsContents[i], COLUMNS * sizeof(int));
```

Comment: That idea is not wrong, but some of the details are off. For example, where you have `ROWS` you need `COLUMNS`, and vice versa.

Comment: I was hesitating for a moment because I had wrong numbers in project but that's a good solution, indeed. +1

Answer (score 2):

Allocate a 1D array of ints of size ROWS*COLUMNS; assign each listOfTxtsContents[i][j] to element i*COLUMNS+j.